# Make jPlayer play again without page reload

Tags: ajax, jplayer

Our users us IE7 and I need to play a sound if there are alert messages for dispatchers.

This works fine when the page is loaded but if the dispatcher leaves a page open and messages have been received previously and responded to.... then when new messages are received, the sound does not seem to work.

What am I doing wrong in using jPlayer? I just want to play the sound continuously as long as messages are there.

My Ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Messages/ViewMessages.aspx/GetMessages",
    data: "{messageId:" + 45 + "}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 60000,
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.d.length > 0) {
            showPanic(data.d);
            var sound = "/JavaScript/jQuery/UI/js/Audio/Air Plane Ding-SoundBible.com496729130.mp3";
     playSound(sound);
        }
        else {
            $("#dialog").dialog("destroy");
        }

    }

function playSound(sound) {
            $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
                ready: function() {
                    $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                        mp3: sound
                    }).jPlayer("play");
                },
                loop: true,
                swfPath: "/JavaScript/jQuery/UI/js/jQuery.jPlayer.2.1.0/Jplayer.swf",
                supplied: "mp3"
            });
            $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("play");}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this change in `playSound`. [Click here to run the code in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75lb/gDxma/).

```
function playSound(sound) {
    var $player = $("#jquery_jplayer_1");
    if ($player.data().jPlayer && $player.data().jPlayer.internal.ready === true) {
        $player.jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3: sound
        }).jPlayer("play");
    }
    else {
        $player.jPlayer({
            ready: function() {
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                    mp3: sound
                }).jPlayer("play");
            },
            loop: true,
            swfPath: "/JavaScript/jQuery/UI/js/jQuery.jPlayer.2.1.0/Jplayer.swf",
            supplied: "mp3"
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This throws a null exception at  $("#jquery_jplayer_1").data().jPlayer.internal.ready === true). Thanks for the suggestion though. I am trying to follow this idea to pause and play.

Comment: sorry - yes, it would do on first execution.. i edited the code to test for null first..

Comment: Sorry, I still get the null exception. Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: sorry bro, i should have tested my code properly.. i have edited the post again, adding a link to a Fiddle where you can run and test it for yourself.

Comment: That would be sister :). But the problem is with IE7 not being able to handle reading a null object. This solution works fine in other browsers.

Comment: whoops, sorry sister! how embarassing, haha.. i tested the fiddle in IE7 - works fine.. Did you try it? If not, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/75lb/gDxma/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5779/discussion-between-crazydiamond-and-lloyd)

Comment: No worries! I figured out that the problem was that the div for my jPlayer was inside of a messageDialog and when I opened that dialog, I lost access to the functionality within the jPlayer because the message dialog had a class of clearfix. Good news is that it is working very well. Bad news is I took too long to figure out a basic mistake.

Comment: ah, i see.. don't worry - learning from our mistakes is what makes us stronger!

Answer (score 0):

My jPlayer div was within a class that implemented Display:none. That removes access to play, pause, stop features of jPlayer.